# I create some tables in SqlDeveloper but I can not see the data stored in the tables. Why I can't see the data in my tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I created a sql script to create and populate tables. The script was run in SqlDeveloper.

When I run the query

```
Select * from table_name
```

in Sql Developer it does work and returns the data from the table.

But when I open the Command Prompt and I login and execute the same query I receive the message "no rows selected". I also tried to run

```
SELECT table_name FROM user_tables;
```

in command line and it does work, all the tables names are returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you did not commit the transaction. Issue a

```
COMMIT;
```

after your `INSERT` statements.

Comment: I have done this so many times with Oracle that I assume you are right about the issue.

Comment: If it's not this, make sure you're logged into the same database as the same user